# Conversion of reports from ssrs 2008 to ssrs 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We currently have a requirement to create ssrs reports . We are using Sql Server 2008 currently. But we are planning to shift to Sql Server 2012 soon.  I wanted to know if I create reports in SSRS 2008 . Will they need any conversion when I use SSRS 2012. If so would it be minor or major changes.

I just want to know this so that I can decide if its better to create reports now or wait till we migrate to Sql Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion would be very minor.  From what I am seeing MS is moving away from SSRS.  2008R2 and 2012 are virtually identical except minor namespace changes.  2008 to 2012 is very minor.  The report engine underneath is very similar.  2005 and up is a very big change, anything else is very minor.

I would create the reports now as I highly doubt it would change much.  You can always download a free version for development of SQL 2012 express with advanced tools, which has ssrs in it.  Then you can test a transfer without getting a full edition.